# Nature of an entire function when real part of $f(z) \geq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function with $Re(f(z)) \geq 0$ for all $z$ in $\Bbb C$.
Here if we consider $(\exp(z))(-f(z))$ {composition of two entire functions} is entire. Let $g(z) = e^{(-f(z))}$, then maximum magnitude of $g(z)$ turns to be $1$ as $Re(f(z))\geq 0$ and so maximum value of $\exp(Re(-f(z)))$ will be $1$ at $0$. So we get $g$ as entire and bounded function, hence constant. And therefore on solving we get $f$ is also constant.

Now if I consider $Re(f(z))=mod(z)$, for all $z$ in $\Bbb C$

- for different value we give, we get different value for $Re(f(z))$. So $f(z)$ cannot be constant.
- But from the argument I made above, function with real part $\geq 0$ must be constant. So here $Re(f(z))=mod(z)$ is positive.
  Should I consider whether $Re(f(z))$ is harmonic or not. Or ?
  I'm not able to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be much thankful.

Comment: If a function $g$ is armonic and non constant, $g$ restricted to $\{|z|\le r\}$ attains its maximum and minimum at the boundary $\{|z|=1\}$, while your function attains its minimum at $0$, and so we have a contradiction.

Comment: g is not restricted to the unit circle. I meant that |g(z)|=|exp(-x-iy)|=|exp(-x)||exp(-iy)|=|exp(-x)|*1. Now since x≥0, 1/exp(x) will be less than or equal to 1.

Comment: I know that $g$ is not restricted to the unit circle. However, if you restric $g$, you can apply the maximum principle to obtain a contradiction

Comment: Okay, but if an entire function does not attain it's bound on boundary we can conclude it's a constant function so the conclusion turns to be g is constant.

Comment: Thus, $Re(f(z))$ should be constant, but it is not, and so is not harmonic